# Macro for renaming sequence- functions

Tags: scheme, racket

Can I create a macro so that I can call `sequence-` functions with a `s-`? Hence, I should be able to write `s-length`, `s-filter` and `s-map` instead of `sequence-length`, `sequence-filter` and `sequence-map`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`filtered-in`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Frequire..rkt%29._filtered-in%29%29) from `racket/require` to perform this sort of transformation. Here’s a simple example:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/require
         (filtered-in (λ (name) (regexp-replace #rx"^sequence-" name "s-"))
                      racket/sequence))

(s-ref '(1 2 3) 1)
```

---

If you find yourself using this sort of thing often, it wouldn’t be too hard to write a [require transformer](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28tech._require._transformer%29) that would expand to `filtered-in`:

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax racket/require-transform
                     syntax/parse)
         racket/require)

(define-syntax reprefix-in
  (make-require-transformer
   (syntax-parser
     [(_ original-prefix:id new-prefix:id require-spec:expr ...)
      #:with replacer (string-append "^" (regexp-quote (symbol->string (syntax-e #'original-prefix))))
      #:with replacement (symbol->string (syntax-e #'new-prefix))
      (expand-import #'(filtered-in (λ (name) (regexp-replace (regexp 'replacer) name 'replacement))
                                    (combine-in require-spec ...)))])))
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
(require (reprefix-in sequence- s- racket/sequence))
(s-ref '(1 2 3) 1)
```

Comment: Should this be put in a library somewhere?

Comment: @AlexKnauth Possibly. Having it in `racket/require` might make sense, but I’ve been reluctant to add new things to `base` given that it’s the only package that (obviously) can’t be used on older Racket versions. I’m not sure having it in a separate package would make *too* much sense, but with some other require/provide transformers I’ve written, it might be a little more worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. To versing levels of cludgyness.

The way I highly recommend you do, however, is to use [`rename-in`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=rename-in) To rename each of these functions on import. So for example, your code would look like:

```
#lang racket

(require (rename-in racket/sequence
                    [sequence-length s-length]
                    [sequence-map s-map]
                    [sequence-filter s-filter]
                    ...))
```

There are other more advanced ways to do this that do not require you to explicitly list out each identifier, using [`module->exports`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=module-aexports#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._module-~3eexports%29%29), [`regexp-match`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html?q=regexp-match#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._regexp-match%29%29), [`format-id`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-util.html?q=format-id#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsyntax..rkt%29._format-id%29%29), and [`make-require-transformer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html?q=require-transformer#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Frequire-transform..rkt%29._make-require-transformer%29%29). But this seems to brittle to me and you're better off being explicit about which names you want to rename.